# Getting storeId in a cron job

Tags: magento

Many searches didn't help at all :(.
I'm trying to get the store id in a function executed in a cron job...
I've read that I could add a parameter in my cron schedule, but this is not what I want. I really need to get it dynamically.

Any help will be GREATLY appreciated !

Edit : in this function, I handle some products. Their getStoreId() always gives me 0... could I change that ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to use some like this code:

```
$defStoreId = Mage::app()->getDefaultStoreView()->getStoreId();
```

Hope this helps.